# Getting result as Array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods

We are learning how to use Stream Reader, and i got some problems with methods, actually when im trying to get return value it doesn't work.

```
static void FindeMinMaxVerkauf(Verkauf[] arr, out Verkauf min, out Verkauf max)
{

    double min2 = 10000;
    double max2 = 0;
    int min3 = 0;
    int max3 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if((arr[i].StückPreis * arr[i].Stückzahl) < min2)
        {
            min2 = arr[i].StückPreis * arr[i].Stückzahl;
            min3 = i;
        }
        if ((arr[i].StückPreis * arr[i].Stückzahl) > max2)
        {
            max2 = arr[i].StückPreis * arr[i].Stückzahl;
            max3 = i;
        }
    }
    min = arr[min3];
    max = arr[max3];
}
```

This is how im trying to get return value

```
double min,max;
FindeMinMaxVerkauf(alle, out min, out max);
Console.WriteLine("Verkäufe mit kleinsten Preis " + min + "Verkäufe mit größten Preis" + max );
```

But it says

> CS1503    Argument "3": Konvertierung von "`out double`" in "out
>   _61_T_Shirts.Verkauf" nicht möglich.

It means converting from `double` in `Tshirts`... *not possible*. I dont know how to fix it really.

2. This is my second methode:

   ```
   static Verkauf FindeHöchsteStückzahl(Verkauf[] arr)
   {
       int anz = 0;
       int pos = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
       {
           if(arr[i].Stückzahl > anz)
           {
               anz = arr[i].Stückzahl;
               pos = i;
           }
       }
       return arr[pos];
   }
   ```

And this is how I'm trying to get return value:

```
FindeHöchsteStückzahl(alle);
Console.WriteLine("Höchste Stückzahl: " + alle );
```

But I'm getting Array as result:

```
Höchste Stückzahl: _61_T_Shirts.Verkauf[]
```

3. I mean this:

   ```
   static Verkauf[] FindeVerkäufe(Verkauf[] arr, string farbe)
   {
       int j = 0;
       Verkauf[] finderverk = new Verkauf[10000];
       for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
       {
           if(arr[i].Farbe == farbe)
           {
               finderverk[j] = arr[i];
               j++;
           }
       }
       Array.Resize(ref finderverk, j);
       return finderverk;
   }
   ```

   }
   }

I need help ;D

Comment: I wasn't aware you can use German chars in c#.:)

Comment: `out Verkauf min` is not `out double min` - and you don't seem to have implemented an `implicit` conversion either

Comment: Yes , it not usually but we can :D

Comment: @UnholySheep i did before this 2-3 methods and i used same method but this one i dont get it

Comment: `static void FindeMinMaxVerkauf(Verkauf[] arr, out Verkauf min, out Verkauf max)` -> `static void FindeMinMaxVerkauf(Verkauf[] arr, out double min, out double max)`. I highly doubt you did this exact same code with different methods, it wouldn't have worked there either. So unless you can provide a [mcve] proving it does, this is your answer

Comment: And for your second method - you are not getting an array as a result, you are completely ignoring the `return` value of it and then trying to print the array variable. You should really read your class notes more carefully (and ask your teacher such things)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem. Why not just *follow suit* and declare `min` as well as `max` being `Verkauf`?

```
Verkauf min, max; // Verkauf, not double
FindeMinMaxVerkauf(alle, out min, out max);

// String interpolation - $"... {value} ..." is more readable
// We have min and max of type Verkauf; we want to print out StückPreis: 
Console.WriteLine(
  $"Verkäufe mit kleinsten Preis {min.StückPreis} Verkäufe mit größten Preis {max.StückPreis}");
```

Second problem. You have to *save* the result of `FindeHöchsteStückzahl` call and then display it, not the initial array:

```
// Save the result of the method call (sorry for the umlaut)
var hoch = FindeHöchsteStückzahl(alle);

// ... and print out the result (hoch), not the initial array 
// If you haven't implement `ToString()` in the Verkauf class
// You, probably, don't want {hoch} but {hoch.StückPreis}:
// Console.WriteLine($"Höchste Stückzahl: {hoch.StückPreis}");  
Console.WriteLine($"Höchste Stückzahl: {hoch}");
```

**Edit:** If you want to return an *array*, i.e. `Verkauf[]` (First and Second problem combined):

```
// Array: 1st item is min, 2nd one is max
static Verkauf[] MinMaxVerkauf(Verkauf[] value) {
  Verkauf min, max; 
  FindeMinMaxVerkauf(alle, out min, out max);

  return new Verkauf[] {min, max};
} 

...

var minmax = MinMaxVerkauf(alle);

Console.WriteLine(
  $"Verkäufe mit kleinsten Preis {minmax[0].StückPreis} Verkäufe mit größten Preis {minmax[1].StückPreis}");
```

**Edit 2:** When you want to *query* your data (find out the max `StückPreis` of some `Farbe`) try using *Linq* which has been specially designed for such purpose:

```
using System.Linq;

...

// See how it's easy (the third problem in the question):
static Verkauf[] FindeVerkäufe(Verkauf[] arr, string farbe) {
  return arr
    .Where(stuck => stuck.Farbe == farbe)
    .ToArray();  
}

...

string farbe = "Rot";

double max = alle
  .Where(stuck => stuck.Farbe == farbe)
  .Max(stuck => stuck.StückPreis); 

double min = alle
  .Where(stuck => stuck.Farbe == farbe)
  .Min(stuck => stuck.StückPreis); 

Console.WriteLine(
  $"Farbe {farbe}: Verkäufe mit kleinsten Preis {min.StückPreis} Verkäufe mit größten Preis {max.StückPreis}");
```

Comment: Thanks the first one worked, but the second one didn't do u have an email where i can reach you ?

Comment: @Kevin Garnick: I see; if you haven't implement `ToString()` method in the `Verkauf` class (i.e. .net doesn't know *how to print out* `Verkauf` instance), you have to put it explicitly: `Console.WriteLine($"Höchste Stückzahl: {hoch.StückPreis}");`. You can see my eMail in my profile

Comment: Thanks i have 1 more question when i have Array in Methode and i want to return Array how should i do it ?

static Verkauf[] FindeVerkäufe(Verkauf[] arr, string farbe)

and the return is 

return finderverk;

Comment: @Kevin Garnick: Having an *array* you want to output the array as well, you can do it like this: `static Verkauf[] SomeMethod(Verkauf[] value) {/*implementation*/}`

Comment: i myb formed my question bad , i want to get return value(output) like in the 1. and 2. method

Comment: I have in methode array and string , how should i give outoup ?

Comment: @Kevin Garnick: So given `alle` array you want to return the array of two items (`min` is the first one and `max` is the second one)? Do I usderstand you right?

Comment: Not really :) 

static Verkauf[] FindeVerkäufe(Verkauf[] arr, string farbe)

And I want output arr alle and the string Farbe , should i paste my methode in the comment so u can see clearly ?

Comment: static Verkauf[] FindeVerkäufe(Verkauf[] arr, string farbe)
        {
            int j = 0;
            Verkauf[] finderverk = new Verkauf[10000];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if(arr[i].Farbe == farbe)
                {
                    finderverk[j] = arr[i];
                    j++;
                }
            }
            Array.Resize(ref finderverk, j);
            return finderverk;
        }


Here is the method

Comment: @Kevin Garnick: when *quering* the data (say, `Max` over all items with some `Farbe`) try using *Linq* which is by far easier to read and implment than complex loops

Comment: is there any email,phone where i can contact you ?

Comment: @Kevin Garnick: please, go to my profile - https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319407/dmitry-bychenko?tab=profile click on E-mail (ckick to reveal) and enter captcha 
(sorry for not providing it openly - spam)

Answer (score 0):

Try using Linq.

It's build in, and does make the code much more readable:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ar = new Buy[]{
            new Buy(){Price = 1, Name = "shirt"}, 
            new Buy(){Price = 2, Name = "hat"}, 
            new Buy(){Price = 3, Name = "dog"}
        };

        Console.WriteLine(ar.OrderByDescending(b => b.Price).First().Name);
        Console.WriteLine(ar.OrderBy(b => b.Price).First().Name);
    }

    internal class Buy{
        public int Price;
        public string Name;
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
dog
shirt
```

This should lead you in the right direction.